# Activiti | Create a generic Service task to send XML Over HTTP

Tags: activiti

As continued part of our Activiti Evaluation we are doing a PoC to migrate our existing templates to BPMN Specs. For that we need to migrate 
existing tasks and one of the most critical is a task that would communicate with mother application using XML over HTTP. I am planning to create a 
service task (Java Delegate) for this purpose. This task has to be reusable so that I can use it in different process definitions and also in the 
same definition for different invocation within the same definition. To achieve this, the service task needs to be provided with initialization 
parameters as well as the XML body. The initialization parameters include:

```
URL of the mother application
Authentication Credentials
```

My Query and confusion is how to best implement this requirement.

For example, I can keep the initialization parameters in a properties file and create a sub process with its own service task to read this file. This sub process would then be part of the main process. 
Alternatively, I can read this properties file in the service task, instead of creating 
a sub process

```
What is the best practice/guideline for this type of scenario.
```

The XML body (means the content of XML) would vary as per the process definitions and would need to be parametrized. What is best way to provide XML to the service task, given the fact that this is reusable task. For example, shall I define the XML as part of the .bpmn.xml file or should I create
a separate template files with an identifier and use them in my service task(the one which would send xml over http)
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We are using Activiti BPMN heavily in our products and we never thought feeding XML to a BPMN file. We always generate XML files on the fly by the help of Service Tasks. In this case we don't worry about the bpmn files, we just update generation mechanism and XML file is generated without touching deployed process definitions.

This generation mechanism also externalized from the source code, we use Velocity templates and processes only gives required parameters to service task so that it can decide which template to use.

Our cases seems alike, we use only one service task for each request, it just passes the parameters to some template according to some other parameters.

Comment: Thanks @GokcenG. At this moment I am stuck with a different task. So I am not able to devote time to Activiti Evaluation. I will try the approach suggested by you once I get free and update you.